# Elemento sobrepondo todo o restante

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou criando um projeto **decodificador binário**, quis "enfeitar" colocando um fundo estilo Matrix, porém ele sobrepõe todos os outros elementos presente no [html](/questions/tagged/html)

```js
// geting canvas by Boujjou Achraf
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//making the canvas full screen
c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

//chinese characters - taken from the unicode charset
var matrix = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789@#$%^&*()*&^%+-/~{[|`]}";
//converting the string into an array of single characters
matrix = matrix.split("");

var font_size = 10;
var columns = c.width / font_size; //number of columns for the rain
//an array of drops - one per column
var drops = [];
//x below is the x coordinate
//1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
   drops[x] = 1;

//drawing the characters
function draw() {
   //Black BG for the canvas
   //translucent BG to show trail
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

   ctx.fillStyle = "#f4427d"; //green text
   ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
   //looping over drops
   for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
      //a random chinese character to print
      var text = matrix[Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix.length)];
      //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
      ctx.fillText(text, i * font_size, drops[i] * font_size);

      //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
      //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis
      if (drops[i] * font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
         drops[i] = 0;

      //incrementing Y coordinate
      drops[i]++;
   }
}

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```css
/* By Boujjou Achraf*/

/*basic reset */

* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

body {
   background: black;
}

canvas {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0.4;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <canvas id="c">
      <h1 id="h1"><em>Insira o código binário</em></h1>
      <input type="number" name="binario" id="bint"><br>
      <button id="decod"></button>
      <output id="bout"></output>
   </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

<sup>Fonte: https://codepen.io/wefiy/pen/WPpEwo</sup>

Comment: Maicke, seja muito bem-vindo ao [pt.so], antes de mais nada, veja [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder elaborar uma boa pergunta. Não use códigos em imagens, pois não é bem visto pela comunidade, para isto, veja também [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: Aqui utilizamos a formatação **Markdown**, veja [ajuda na formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ao fazer perguntas/respostas.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Disponha amigo! o problema é que você está utilizando o elemento `canvas` que está ocupando toda largura/altura da página, imagine uma "cortina cobrindo uma janela"

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, no HTML, coloque seu conteúdo fora do canvas:

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<h1 id="h1"><em>Insira o código binário</em></h1>
<input type="number" name="binario" id="bint"><br>
<button id="decod"></button>
<output id="bout"></output>
```

Depois utilize `position: absolute` no CSS do canvas para que ele não ocupe espaço e empurre o resto para baixo. Assim ele ficará atrás do resto:

```
canvas {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   opacity: 0.4;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ele meio que continua por cima, eu não consigo por nada no "<input type="number" name="binario" id="bint"><br>" não consigo clicar nem nada...
edit: coloquei os demais como position:relative, e se sobressaiu ao "matrix" obg a ajudar ^^

Comment: @Maicke é porque você deveria ter posto o código relativo ao elemento `canvas` (ou seja, acima dele) mas como você alterou a propriedade **position** do input, irá ter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @gleisin-dev ent, se eu colocasse o canvas, no final do codigo, tudo iria sobrepor o canvas é isso?